# Key/Value pairs not available from gradle.properties when applying external script in buildscript

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I'm using Gradle 3.2.1 (see the `wrapper` task). I have:

**(1)** This `build.gradle` script:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
  }

  apply from: 'gradle/buildscript.gradle', to: buildscript
}

plugins {
  // ...
}

repositories {
  //mavenLocal()
  mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

group 'io.shido'
version "${rootProject.version}"

dependencyManagement {
  imports {
    mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${spring_boot_version}")
  }
}

dependencies {
  apt "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombok_version}"
  compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
  testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion '3.2.1'
}
```

**(2)** This `buildscript.gradle` (located inside `${project.root}/gradle`):

```
//
// Executed in the context of `buildscript { }`
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
  classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:${spring_dependencies_management_version}")
  classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${spring_boot_version}")
}
```

**(3)** And a `gradle.properties` (located in `${project.root}`):

```
#
# Global Project's Properties/Settings
rootProject.version = 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT

#
# Dependency Versions
spring_boot_version = 1.4.2.RELEASE
spring_dependencies_management_version = 0.6.0.RELEASE
```

The issue is that Gradle **can't access the key/value pairs defined inside `gradle.properties` (for any script)** anymore once I have this setup. So I can't access the values for `spring_dependencies_management_version`, `spring_boot_version` (for instance) in the .

Any clues?

**NOTE:** If I don't split up the Gradle configuration in different files, everything is fine, but that's not an option.